# Array to string conversion and 500 server error

Tags: ajax, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to ceate tags with a button to ajax to my controller but when i click it gives me a 500 server error message and Array to string conversion.

Controller

```
public function createTags(Request $request)
    {
        $value = $request->get('value');
        if ($value != '') {
           $tag = new TagModel([
                ['name' => $value]
            ]);
            $tag->save();
            return $success = `<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Tag created</div>`;
        }else{
            return $error = `<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Tag already exist or something went wrong.</div>`; 
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => $success,
            'error' => $error
            ]);
    }
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TagModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = ['tags'];
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

ajax call

```
let patt = new RegExp(/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)/, 'g');
let execute = patt.exec(window.location.href);
let url = (execute && execute.length > 0 ? execute[1] : '') + "/api/createtags";

$(document).on('click', '#createSkill', function (e) {
    let value = $('#types').val();
    const _token = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            value: value,
            _token: _token
        },
        success: function (result){
            console.log(result);


        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    })

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

if i rewrite my controller to db::table(tags), it kind of works but it returns always as a fail

Answer (score 1):

The $tablename in Laravel model should be a string, not array. Replace in TagModel:

```
protected $table = 'tags';
```